# ElasticSearch Faceted Search with Documents with it

Tags: java, rest, search, elasticsearch, spring-data

Is it possible to do a faceted search in ElasticSearch that will return the result that contains the documents associated to that facet? What I means is let's say a facet result is something like this

```
"terms" : [ {
      "term" : "foo",
      "count" : 2
    }
```

And inside that terms, it will contain 2 documents that's related to it. the one that has "foo" in it. is it possible to do that with elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

No. Not at this point of time at least.

And I don't think the developers are going to take Faceting (or the new Aggregation framework) in that direction at all as that will be difficult feature to implement. Poses many problems like which and how many documents to return with each facet and providing the ability to control which and how many documents to return with the facet result may be very difficult.

For your case, its not possible right now.

Comment: Is there any work around if I want to accomplish this? My main goal is to achieve a simple faceted navigation

Comment: Not that I know of. There are no APIs that help you do that. If you want to go brute force, then get the terms using Facets and then execute individual searches for each Facet term to get the documents. To execute multiple searches at once, you can make use of the Multi Search API. So this way you will have to make two requests only to get your desired result. But I suspect it will be slow for a large number of documents.

I am not sure but you can also look into writing a plugin for Elasticsearch to do something similar by using the native APIs. But again, I am no Lucene expert.